# Proving continuity at a point if the restriction to "partitions" of set is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ and let $Q_{1}, Q_{2}, Q_{3}$ and $Q_{4}$ be
the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined such that

\begin{array}{l}
{Q_{1}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \geq 0 \text { and } y \geq 0\right\}} \\
{Q_{2}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \leq 0 \text { and } y \geq 0\right\}} \\
{Q_{3}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \leq 0 \text { and } y \leq 0\right\}} \\
{Q_{4}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \geq 0 \text { and } y \leq 0\right\}}
\end{array}

Suppose that the restriction of the function $f$ to the set $Q_{i}$ is continuous on $Q_{i}$
for $i=1,2,3,4 .$ Prove that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Where should I begin with this?

I realize that the union of all the sets is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that their intersection is $(0,0)$, but I'm unsure how to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the fact that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed for every closed set $C$ in $\mathbb R$. But $$f^{-1}(C)$$ can be written as $$(f^{-1}(C) \cap Q_1) \cup (f^{-1}(C) \cap Q_3) \cup (f^{-1}(C) \cap Q_3) \cup (f^{-1}(C) \cap Q_4)$$ and $(f^{-1}(C) \cap Q_i) $is nothing but the inverse image of $C$ under the restriction of $f$ to $Q_i$. Note that since $Q_i$ is closed any closed subset of it is also closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: "Note that since $Q_i$ is closed any closed subset of it is also closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$." Could you show why this is true without using any topology?